# Docker Timezone in Ubuntu 16.04 Image

Tags: datetime, docker, containers

I have created a Docker container using the Ubuntu 16.04 image.

```
docker run -it -d --name containername -v /var/www/public --privileged ubuntu
```

after creating the container, I checked the date inside the container:

```
$ date
Tue Oct 25 08:10:34 UTC 2016
```

But, I need it to use the **Asia/Kolkata** timezone. So I tried changing the `/etc/timezone` file, then `docker stop` and `docker start` the container, but **it doesn't work. It still shows the same time.**

How can I change the time zone in the Docker container after creating it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Updating `/etc/timezone` is the usual way, but there's a [bug in Xenial](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806) which means that doesn't work.

Instead you need to create a link from the desired timezone to `etc/localtime`:

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial     
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific-New /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Comment: Instead of Pacific-New, which one is for Mountain?

Comment: The only path my container has under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` is `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC`, so that does not work ;(

Comment: dpkg-query: package 'tzdata' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: tzdata is not installed

Comment: echo $TZ > /etc/timezone would appear to be the ? debian way? . ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime is the CentOS/Redhat way. However mileage varies more with other OS and applications do not always use the OS timezone. Application service start scripts may need to be customized with the timezone.

Answer (score 31):

In ubuntu 16.04 i was missing tzdata so i had to install it. Working solution was

```
    ENV TZ 'Europe/Tallinn'
    RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    rm /etc/localtime && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean
```

Comment: Note that we need also to add `ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`. Otherwise, `apt-get install -y tzdata` will run in interactive mode.

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
echo "Asia/Kolkata" > /etc/timezone
rm -f /etc/localtime
dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

You have to do `rm /etc/localtime` because of the [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1554806).

Comment: Marvelous. Simplest solution yet.

Answer (score 13):

As [said here](https://serverfault.com/a/683651/93281), the secret is that `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` simply creates `/etc/localtime` as a copy, hardlink or symlink (a symlink is preferred) to a file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`. So it is possible to do this entirely from your Dockerfile. Consider:

```
ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

And as a bonus, TZ will be set correctly in the container as well.

This is also distribution-agnostic, so it works with pretty much anything Linux.

Comment: so much better than to install tzdata, etc

Answer (score 5):

My issue has been solved with this very simple solution (https://serverfault.com/a/826222) : Add timezone in environment variable.

The command is `docker run -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam ...`

Or, using docker-compose, like I do :

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: ./app
        ports:
            - ...
        volumes:
            - ...
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Paris
```

In my case, no more tzdata needed, or volume share with /etc/timezone & /etc/localtime.
Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

If you use docker-compose, just add one line to your `docker-compose.yml` file.

version: '3'

```
services:
  ubuntu-local:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    restart: on-failure
    command: python3 run_my_code.py
    working_dir: /code
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro   # <--add this line to set timezone
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Comment: tzdata package seems not installed under a purpose in official docker ubuntu images, for which it sound better to make usage of original docker mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

I took this approach:

1. Copy file /etc/localtime somewhere.
2. Open it and find the this number (highlighted with yellow) [image]
3. -3 corresponds to Moscow time. For Berlin set -1 . If you need positive value, set UTC2
4. Copy and modify /etc/timezone according to your time zone.
5. Link them to your container

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common apt-utils locales tzdata

RUN echo "tzdata tzdata/Areas select Europe" > timezone.txt
RUN echo "tzdata tzdata/Zones/Europe select Rome" >> timezone.txt
RUN debconf-set-selections timezone.txt
RUN rm /etc/timezone
RUN rm /etc/localtime
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply map the volume while running docker container

-v /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing this issue for a Ubuntu 18.04 docker container. Since `tzdata` package is not installed. There is no `/usr/share/zoneinfo` dir inside the docker. We need to first install `tzdata` and use `dpkg-reconfigure` to set the timezone. The following docker command works for me:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq tzdata && \
    ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
```

Reference: https://dev.to/0xbf/set-timezone-in-your-docker-image-d22

**Note:** Need to run it as `root` user