# apt-get install in Ubuntu 16.04 docker image: '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubuntu-16.04

I'm getting the error message below when running apt-get install from within a rather vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 image:

```
ln: cannot remove '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy
dpkg: error processing package resolvconf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resolvconf
```

The packages seem to be installed correctly, though. How to fix it?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Me Myself <me@myself.com>
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git nano 
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# set the timezone. Note: there is an Ubuntu 16.04 bug which
# requires this to be done this way: 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234847/docker-timezone-in-ubuntu-16-04-image/40235306#40235306
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

RUN locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 de_DE.UTF-8
ENV PATH="/opt/xyz/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Check this Docker bug entry : https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1297

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1297 you can add the following line to your `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN echo "resolvconf resolvconf/linkify-resolvconf boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
```

This way it is possible to install `resolvconf` inside a container.

Answer (score 8):

With the above comment and answer of @Christian Berendt, I still get these errors:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

Here is my complete solution, by adding these lines into the Dockerfile:

These lines help install resolvconf withode debconf errors

```
RUN apt-get update    
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils debconf-utils dialog
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo "resolvconf resolvconf/linkify-resolvconf boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y resolvconf
```

Comment: you should put all this in one RUN command to avoid creating a layer at each step of building this image

Comment: Even better would be to simply include the following line, disabling interactive mode without installing new packages:
```ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive```